# What is $\int\limits_0^1\left\{\frac{1}{x\left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\}}\right\}dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

$\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.

$\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$

I ended up with this double summation:
$$\lim\limits_{\substack{a\to\infty\\b\to\infty}}\sum_{m=1}^{a}\sum_{n=0}^{b}\left(\frac{1}{m}\ln\left(\frac{1-\frac{n+m}{n+m+1}}{1-\frac{n+m+1}{n+m+2}}\right)-\int_{\frac{1}{m}\frac{n+m}{n+m+1}}^{\frac{1}{m}\frac{n+m+1}{n+m+2}}\operatorname{floor}\left(\frac{1}{1-mx}\right)dx\right)$$

With $a=22$ and $b=100$, I approximated it at $0.432173036271$.

I got stuck at evaluating the integral of the floor function and I doubt I will be able to solve the double summation. Here is the [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bxwoxfrplp) graph I was working in if that is of any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do I do the substack in MathJax? It is not rendering for some reason.

Comment: @MartinR That is correct, thank you.

Comment: @Zima It doesn't seem like it. Otherwise, wouldn't the first two equations on this graph be equal? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e4yl9mf5n9

Comment: @Sahaj Yes, I'll add that to the post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$A partial answer. We should find: $$\begin{align}I&=\int_0^1\left\{\frac{1}{x\cdot\{\frac{1}{x}\}}\right\}\d x\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}\left\{\frac{1}{x(\frac{1}{x}-n)}\right\}\d x\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=n+1}^\infty\int_{\frac{m-1}{mn}}^{\frac{m}{(m+1)n}}\left(\frac{1}{1-nx}-m\right)\d x\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=n+1}^\infty\left[\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)-\frac{1}{m+1}\right]\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\lim_{N\to\infty}[\ln(N)-\ln(n+1)-H_{N+1}+H_{n+1}]\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n+1}-\ln(n+1)-\gamma}{n}\\&=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\gamma-(H_n-\ln(n+1))}{n}\end{align}$$But I don't believe I know any nice representations for the error $H_n-\ln(n+1)-\gamma$ and don't know how to proceed. I am certain such representations exist, though. I mean, I can cook up some basic integrals but they don't have a nice form. It is nice to observe the numerators in the final form of that series are precisely the differences between the differences in area between the graphs of $1/\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $1/x$ over $[1,n+1]$ and the limit of these differences, $\gamma$. So crudely you could rewrite the summands as $\frac{\gamma}{n}-\frac{1}{n}\int_1^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor}-\frac{1}{x}\right)\d x$ but I doubt that that is useful.

Comment: That's also as far as I got. Well, it's as far as Mathematica got, and then it could only give me a numerical answer of about $0.470947$ for the final summation.

Comment: If we take the asymptotic expansion $H_n = \ln n + \gamma + \frac1{2n} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{2k n^{2k}}$, then we can get approximations for the final answer by truncating it. Truncating it at $\frac1{2n}$ gives an approximation of $\frac12$. Truncating it at $k=1$ gives an approximation of $\frac13 + \frac{\pi^2}{72} \approx 0.4704$.

Comment: @ТymaGaidash yes. I tried but with the extra log term I couldn’t see it leading anywhere